# How to clear contents after generating a PDF file?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, dompdf

I have a scenario here.

I have a web application(coded in CodeIgniter) which stores registration certificates. What I do is that I am loading my data from the database and then looping using foreach loop and then get contents for each row and then i pass the data to my view. Then I use dompdf library to generate the PDF certificate each store in its folder/directory with the same name as the id of the row.

The issue is that, when the loop is completed, the directory are created correctly but the content in the certificate have the same data which is the data for the same row.

I have attached my code,please assist where i am wrong and why all contents have the same data.

```
foreach ($business_info as $value) {

     ob_start();

       $business_id = $value->business_id;

         $data['businessowners'] = $this->this_business->this_businessowners($business_id);
         $data['certificate_data'] = $this->this_business->this_print_certificate($business_id);
         $data['account_owners'] = $this->this_business->this_accountowners($business_id);
         $data['is_all_partners'] = $this->db->query("select * from check_bank_operator($business_id)")->row();


         $html=$this->load->view('certificate', $data,true);

        //$folder = FCPATH . 'mfumo/data/certificates/'.$business_id;


         $folder = FCPATH . 'mfumo/data/docs/business/'.$business_id;
         if (!is_dir($folder))                             
         {
           mkdir($folder,0777, TRUE);
         }

        $save_path = 'mfumo/data/docs/business/'.$business_id .'/'.$business_id.'_cert.pdf';
        $system_root_file = FCPATH . $save_path;
        $this->load->helper('dompdf/pdf');
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'portrait');
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->get_canvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption('', 'n.*7&4%i:[}', array('print'));
        $output = $dompdf->output();
        $data = file_put_contents($system_root_file, $output);
        ob_clean()



 }
```

Comment: What is `this_business`?

Comment: each and every `$value` you need to create new PDF ??

Comment: this_business is the model with the mysql queries

Comment: that is what am doing

Comment: I am looping and for each $value i am creating a PDF and but for all the PDFs generated,they contain information of the first $value value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

foreach ($business_info as $value) {

```
   $business_id = $value->business_id;

     $data['businessowners'] = $this->this_business->this_businessowners($business_id);
     $data['certificate_data'] = $this->this_business->this_print_certificate($business_id);
     $data['account_owners'] = $this->this_business->this_accountowners($business_id);
     $data['is_all_partners'] = $this->db->query("select * from check_bank_operator($business_id)")->row();


     $html=$this->load->view('certificate', $data,true);

    //$folder = FCPATH . 'mfumo/data/certificates/'.$business_id;


     $folder = FCPATH . 'mfumo/data/docs/business/'.$business_id;
     if (!is_dir($folder))                             
     {
       mkdir($folder,0777, TRUE);
     }

    $save_path = 'mfumo/data/docs/business/'.$business_id .'/'.$business_id.'_cert.pdf';
    $system_root_file = FCPATH . $save_path;
    $this->load->helper('dompdf/pdf');
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'portrait');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->get_canvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption('', 'n.*7&4%i:[}', array('print'));
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    $data = file_put_contents($system_root_file, $output);
    unset($dompdf);
    unset($data);
```

}